# Cocos3D - 'May not respond' warning on dot notation

Tags: ios7, cocos3d

I am using Cocos3D and this function give me a 'may not respond' warning:

```
[CClayer.CC3scene someFunctionFromCC3scene];
```

I know one way to resolve this is to have a `Function` in `CCLayer` to make `CC3scene` call `someFunctionFromCC3scene`. But is there any other way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

More likely you're not importing the corresponding header. For example #import "CC3Scene.h". I suppose this can happen if the return type of the `CC3scene` property is `id` instead of the actual class.

Or the compiler is correct about this and it will crash with "does not respond to selector" when you run it. In that case CC3Scene does not implement the `someFunctionFromCC3scene` selector. Check spelling and parameters, and of course that the class actually implements that selector and has it declared in the @interface.

Comment: I tried #import and @class CC3scene but the problem still persist.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of your example, there are several things that might be going wrong:

You might be confusing `CCLayer` with `CC3Layer`. `CC3Layer` is a subclass of `CCLayer` that supports displaying a 3D scene. Be sure you are instantiating a `CC3Layer`.

If you really are using a `CC3Layer` and the `CC3Scene` property (which is actually `cc3Scene`) is returning an instance of `CC3Scene`, then, as LearnCocos2D indicates, verify that the method you are invoking actually exists in the `CC3Scene` class. If you provide the specific method name here, then I can provide further help.

If the `someFunctionFromCC3Scene` is actually defined and implemented in your custom subclass, then you should cast the `CC3Scene` instance to your custom subclass before invoking that method:

```
[((MyCC3Scene*)aCC3Layer.cc3Scene) someFunctionFromMyCC3Scene];
```

...Bill

Comment: Strange. The function is called. But I get this `[info] Deallocating TepaScene 'Unnamed':22 on thread <NSThread: 0x9f0afa0>{name = (null), num = 1}` and the code inside the function is not being performed.

Comment: I went other way and managed it by NSNotificationCenter. But still wonder what was causing this error.